# Java Stream not working as expected in Character or Byte array

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

```
// code snippet 1:-
Stream.of(Paths.get("/tmp").toFile().listFiles()).forEach(System.out::println);

output:  
/tmp/.keystone_install_lock
/tmp/.vbox-srirammuthaiah-ipc  
/tmp/a.txt  
/tmp/b.txt  
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.1enUeBRkSj  
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.KIcK6WPwWH  
/tmp/mbbservice.pid  
/tmp/mv.txt  
/tmp/wifi-12-03-2016__18:16:24.log 


// code snippet 2:-
String line = "Hello how are you";
Stream.of(line.toCharArray()).forEach(System.out::println);

output:  
Hello how are you
```

Here list of files are considered as file array and processed one by one whereas string to char array conversion doesn't have effect in stream of method and is processed as a single string.

what I'm expecting is output for second code snippet should something like below as same as file stream processing.

```
Expected output:  
H  
e  
l  
l  
o  

h  
o  
w  

a  
r  
e  

y  
o  
u
```

Much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking two different overloads of `Stream.of(..)`:

```
Stream.of(T object)
Stream.of(T... objects)
```

`toCharArray()` returns a `char[]` which is not a `T[]` since primitive arrays are specific types different from a generic `T[]` (which is an `Object[]` under the hood).

So basically `listFiles()` return a `File[]` which matches the signature `of(T... object)` and produces a stream containing all the `File` instances while `toCharArray()` returns a `char[]` which matches `of(T object)` and returns a stream containing just that element.

Mind that String class already provides `chars()` method which returns an `IntStream` for your purpose:

```
"Hello how are you".chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c) }
"Hello how are you".chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).forEach(...)
```

Comment: I couldn't find chars() method in java.lang.String class, can you explain me which class are you mentioning?

Comment: @Sriram M: `chars()`  is defined in the `CharSequence` interface.

Answer (score 1):

The `Stream.of(char[])` isn't going to work, because `char` is a primitive type. Instead, you can use an `IntStream.range` and then use that to get the characters. Like,

```
String line = "Hello how are you";
char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
IntStream.range(0, chars.length).forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.println(chars[i]));
```

Which matches your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your response.